# How invalidate beaker_cache in Pylons?

Tags: caching, pylons, beaker

Need to invalidate a cache created by `beaker_cache` decorator for a specific controller action:

```
from pylons.decorators.cache import beaker_cache

class SampleController(BaseController):

    @beaker_cache()
    def home(self):
        c.data = expensive_call()
        return render('/home.myt')

    def __clear_home_cache(self):
        pass
```

Can I use `region_invalidate()` inside __clear_home_cache function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find out how to invalidate stuff cached by `beaker_cache` decorator is to look at how it works and what it does. It is defined in `pylons.decorators.cache` module, [here's the corresponding source file](https://github.com/Pylons/pylons/blob/master/pylons/decorators/cache.py) on GitHub.

Basically you're looking for the logic that chooses *namespace* and *cache key* for a given controller action. This is done by [create_cache_key()](https://github.com/Pylons/pylons/blob/master/pylons/decorators/cache.py#L130) function in that file. And, incidentally, that function has a helpful comment:

```
Example:
    from pylons import cache
    from pylons.decorators.cache import create_cache_key
    namespace, key = create_cache_key(MyController.some_method)
    cache.get_cache(namespace).remove(key)
```